# how to get the count of customers and display them against product?

Tags: oracle

[image: Click here to know my doubt]

I am able to get the count of customers against the product but for me it is difficult to display like how i have mentioned in the above image.

Comment: This is not a complete question.  Please _edit_ your question and include your table data as actual text, each line indented by 4 spaces.  Then, show us the query you have attempted, or if not, why you couldn't try a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a left join and count function:

```
select p.product,
    count(c.name) as cust_count
from product p
left join customer c
on p.product = c.product
group by p.product;
```

This is assuming you need zero count for the products that don't have any customers.

If that's not the case, you can use simple aggregation:

```
select product,
    count(*) as cust_count
from customer
group by product;
```